# Select Not Displaying Value (ReactJS/Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a multi-select form control, however, whenever I select something it does not get rendered. The function `handleChange` does get the `event.target.value` but it does not seem to add to the roleIds state. Furthermore, the `console.log` for the variable `selected` does not log anything to console.

Component Code:

```
const allRoleIds = [
    "12345678",
    "98765423",
    "56465735683578",
  ];

const [roleIds, setRoleIds] = React.useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setRoleIds(event.target.value);
  }

  const [cassowaries, setCassowaries] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: "Cassowary Name", field: "name" },
      {
        title: "Cassowary Roles",
        field: "roles",
        render: (rowData) => {
          return (
            <li>
              {rowData.roles.map((role) => (
                <Chip label={role} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </li>
          );
        },
        editComponent: (props) => (
          <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel>Roles</InputLabel>
            <Select
              multiple
              value={roleIds}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip" />}
              renderValue={(selected) => {
                console.log(selected);

                return (
                  <div className={classes.chips}>
                    {selected.map((value) => (
                      <Chip
                        key={value}
                        label={value}
                        className={classes.chip}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                );
              }}
              // MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {allRoleIds.map((id) => (
                <MenuItem key={id} value={id}>
                  {id}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        ),
      },
      { title: "Penguin", field: "penguin" },
    ],
    data: [{ name: "Mehmet", roles: roleIds, penguin: true }],
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `concat` in your handleChange. Material ui already gives you the array of selected values to you. Sp fix your handleChange everything should be fine.

**Like this**

```js
 function handleChange(event) {
    setRoleIds(event.target.value);
  }
```

[Working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-issue-fix-lnv8i?file=/src/App.js)

**EDIT:**

Based on additional req (see comments):

If a custom multi select component needs to be used inside [materail table editcomponent](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable), then the state of select should not be managed outside but state & onChagne needs to managed inside `editComponent` using the `prop` it provides.

[See working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-issue-fix-new-t812y?file=/src/App.js)

**Code snippet - material ui table**

```js
...
columns: [
      { title: "Tag Name", field: "name" },
      {
        title: "Tag Roles",
        field: "roles",
        render: rowData => {
          return (
            <li>
              {rowData.roles.map(role => (
                <Chip label={role} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </li>
          );
        },
        editComponent: props => {
          console.log("props", props);
          return (
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <InputLabel>Roles</InputLabel>
              <Select
                multiple
                value={props.value}
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip" />}
                renderValue={renderChip}
              >
                {allRoleIds.map(id => (
                  <MenuItem key={id} value={id}>
                    {id}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          );
        }
      },
      { title: "Penguin", field: "penguin" }
    ],
    data: [{ name: "Mehmet", roles: [], penguin: true }]
...
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. If it helps, this is an edit component of a material-table. Nothing still gets selected even though the code looks really similar.

Comment: it should work...see the working demo shared in the answer and compare it with your code.... if still issue, then pls share more code or create a sandbox and share the link

Comment: Please check my original post. I have included more of the code.

Comment: I have transferred it to a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-issue-fix-63gld?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ok - i have updated the answer and put the latest codesandbox... everything shd be working now

Comment: I looked at the new code and everything works but the add button returns an error
`the value prop must be an array when using select component with multiple`

Comment: sorry i shared a wrong codesandbox link in my answer-edit ... i have udpated the answer with correct link .... this one .. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-issue-fix-new-t812y?file=/src/App.js .... its all working fine ...

Comment: Hi, I looked at the new sandbox but try adding something by press the add button on the top right of the table. It will return with an error.

Comment: i see... ok - although your original issue is solved and this is a completely new requirement, I just had a look... just update this `value={!props.value ? [] : props.value}` to the `Select` , it should work all fine.. ...  i have updated the codesandbox as well (same link) ...

Comment: I'm sorry for that new thing. Thank you so much for your time. I appreciate it. It's working now!